# Text in FlatList is not selectable on Android

Tags: react-native

I just upgraded my app from React Native 0.58.5 to 0.61.2 and now I can't select text in FlatList on Android.

I tried to set the selectable = {true} in the Text component in React Native 58.5, and it worked well and could copy the content in the Text.
But after upgraded the React Native version from 0.58.5 to 0.61.2, and couldn't select the text for copy/paste the content in Android 9.0.
Actually it worked on Android 5.0, but didn't work on Android 9.0

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  _renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text selectable>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text selectable>This is selectable Text...</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={['not selectable text', 'not selectable text']}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Expected behavior: Text in Flatlist should be selectable.

Current behavior: Can't select the Text component even though set the selectable={true} in Android 9.0

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by adding a key prop to the Text component:

```
<Text selectable={true} key={Math.random()}>
   {text}
</Text>
```

**EDIT:** The solution above does not seem to work on all RN versions, an alternative solution is setting `removeClippedSubviews={false}` on the `FlatList`

Answer (score 2):

You should enclose this into touchableopacity..

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1 }} 
     onPress={() =>}}>     
        <View>
         <Text selectable>{item}</Text>
        </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, text selectable doesn't work even though enclose into TouchabeOpacity or TouchableWithoutFeedback with disabled={true} props.

Comment: When I tried to long click item, it returned this message `W/TextView: TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled.`

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked temporarily, but then it stopped working without any change to the code. Not sure why :/